# How to make floating sidebar stop floating before the footer to not overlap with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom script with a floating sidebar that keeps floating along the post.

How to stop floating the sidebar and fix it at its current position on screen before it overlaps with the footer by 10px?

I have created a JS fiddle to explain:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dj3cW/1/

You will see that the `#sidebar` overlaps with `#footer`. How to prevent it from further floating down the screen before the `#footer` by `10px`

Keep in mind also that the document height is not fixed because some pages may show more posts than others.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($('#sidebar').offset().top + $("#sidebar").height() > $("#footer").offset().top) {
    $('#sidebar').css('top',-($("#sidebar").offset().top + $("#sidebar").height() - $("#footer").offset().top));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dj3cW/2/

Comment: Please use selector caching - http://mikeadamsnc.com/cache-jquery-selectors-for-better-performance/ (first link I've found). This is probably the most egregious use of jQuery I've ever seen.

Comment: bit extreme...if you want to make it better go ahead, i provided a basic answer